# PostreSQL ERROR: ERROR: MAXVALUE (2147483647) out of sequence data type (smallint)

Tags: sql, .net, postgresql

[image]
I couldn't find the reason for this error. I do not think there is an error in the entered values and SQL code

```
BEGIN;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.cities
(
    id smallint NOT NULL,
    name character varying(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.company_staff_verifications
(
    id integer NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY ( INCREMENT 1 START 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 2147483647 CACHE 1 ),
    user_id integer NOT NULL,
    is_approved boolean NOT NULL,
    created_at timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    approval_date time with time zone,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.company_staffs
(
    user_id integer NOT NULL,
    first_name character varying(50) NOT NULL,
    last_name character varying(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.email_activations
(
    id integer NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY ( INCREMENT 1 START 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 2147483647 CACHE 1 ),
    user_id integer NOT NULL,
    activation_code character varying(200) NOT NULL,
    email character varying(100) NOT NULL,
    is_activated boolean NOT NULL,
    created_at timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    expiration_date timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    activation_date timestamp with time zone,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.employer_updates
(
    id integer NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY ( INCREMENT 1 START 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 2147483647 CACHE 1 ),
    user_id integer NOT NULL,
    company_staff_id integer,
    company_name character varying(100) NOT NULL,
    website character varying(100) NOT NULL,
    corporate_email character varying(100) NOT NULL,
    phone character varying(15) NOT NULL,
    updated_at timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    is_approved boolean NOT NULL,
    is_deleted boolean NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.employers
(
    user_id integer NOT NULL,
    company_name character varying(100) NOT NULL,
    website character varying(100) NOT NULL,
    corporate_email character varying(100) NOT NULL,
    phone character varying(15) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.job_adverts
(
    id integer NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY ( INCREMENT 1 START 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 2147483647 CACHE 1 ),
    employer_id integer NOT NULL,
    job_position_id integer NOT NULL,
    city_id integer NOT NULL,
    description character varying NOT NULL,
    min_salary integer,
    max_salary integer,
    number_of_open_positions integer NOT NULL,
    created_at timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    application_deadline timestamp with time zone,
    is_active boolean NOT NULL,
    is_deleted boolean NOT NULL,
    working_type_id smallint,
    working_time_id smallint,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.job_positions
(
    id integer NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY ( INCREMENT 1 START 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 2147483647 CACHE 1 ),
    title character varying(50) NOT NULL,
    created_at timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    is_active boolean NOT NULL,
    is_deleted boolean NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.job_seeker_cv_educations
(
    id integer NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY ( INCREMENT 1 START 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 2147483647 CACHE 1 ),
    job_seeker_cv_id integer NOT NULL,
    school_name character varying(100) NOT NULL,
    department_name character varying(100) NOT NULL,
    start_date date NOT NULL,
    graduation_date date,
    created_at timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.job_seeker_cv_experiences
(
    id integer NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY ( INCREMENT 1 START 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 2147483647 CACHE 1 ),
    job_seeker_cv_id integer NOT NULL,
    job_position_id integer NOT NULL,
    workplace_name character varying(100) NOT NULL,
    start_date date NOT NULL,
    quit_date date,
    created_at timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.job_seeker_cv_images
(
    id integer NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY ( INCREMENT 1 START 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 2147483647 CACHE 1 ),
    job_seeker_cv_id integer NOT NULL,
    url character varying NOT NULL,
    created_at timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.job_seeker_cv_languages
(
    id integer NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY ( INCREMENT 1 START 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 2147483647 CACHE 1 ),
    job_seeker_cv_id integer NOT NULL,
    language_id character(2) NOT NULL,
    level smallint NOT NULL,
    created_at timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.job_seeker_cv_skills
(
    id integer NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY ( INCREMENT 1 START 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 2147483647 CACHE 1 ),
    job_seeker_cv_id integer NOT NULL,
    name character varying(100) NOT NULL,
    created_at timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.job_seeker_cv_web_sites
(
    id integer NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY ( INCREMENT 1 START 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 2147483647 CACHE 1 ),
    job_seeker_cv_id integer NOT NULL,
    web_site_id smallint NOT NULL,
    address character varying(200) NOT NULL,
    created_at timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.job_seeker_cvs
(
    id integer NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY ( INCREMENT 1 START 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 2147483647 CACHE 1 ),
    job_seeker_id integer NOT NULL,
    cover_letter character varying(300) NOT NULL,
    created_at timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.job_seekers
(
    user_id integer NOT NULL,
    first_name character varying(50) NOT NULL,
    last_name character varying(50) NOT NULL,
    identity_number character(11) NOT NULL,
    birth_date date NOT NULL,
    cv_id integer,
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.job_seekers_favorite_job_adverts
(
    id integer NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY ( INCREMENT 1 START 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 2147483647 CACHE 1 ),
    job_seeker_id integer NOT NULL,
    job_advert_id integer NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.languages
(
    id character(2) NOT NULL,
    name character varying(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.mernis_activations
(
    id integer NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY ( INCREMENT 1 START 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 2147483647 CACHE 1 ),
    user_id integer NOT NULL,
    is_approved boolean NOT NULL,
    created_at timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    approval_date time with time zone,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.users
(
    id integer NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY ( INCREMENT 1 START 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 2147483647 CACHE 1 ),
    email character varying(100) NOT NULL,
    password character varying(100) NOT NULL,
    created_at timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    is_active boolean NOT NULL,
    is_deleted boolean NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.web_sites
(
    id smallint NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY ( INCREMENT 1 START 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 32767 CACHE 1 ),
    name character varying(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.working_times
(
    id smallint NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY ( INCREMENT 1 START 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 32767 CACHE 1 ),
    name character varying(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.working_types
(
    id smallint NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY ( INCREMENT 1 START 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 2147483647 CACHE 1 ),
    id smallint NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY ( INCREMENT 1 START 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 32767 CACHE 1 ),
    name character varying(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

ALTER TABLE public.company_staff_verifications
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
    REFERENCES public.users (id)
    NOT VALID;


ALTER TABLE public.company_staffs
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
    REFERENCES public.users (id)
    NOT VALID;


ALTER TABLE public.email_activations
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
    REFERENCES public.users (id)
    NOT VALID;


ALTER TABLE public.employer_updates
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
    REFERENCES public.employers (user_id)
    NOT VALID;


ALTER TABLE public.employers
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
    REFERENCES public.users (id)
    NOT VALID;


ALTER TABLE public.job_adverts
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (city_id)
    REFERENCES public.cities (id)
    NOT VALID;


ALTER TABLE public.job_adverts
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (employer_id)
    REFERENCES public.employers (user_id)
    NOT VALID;


ALTER TABLE public.job_adverts
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (job_position_id)
    REFERENCES public.job_positions (id)
    NOT VALID;


ALTER TABLE public.job_adverts
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (working_time_id)
    REFERENCES public.working_times (id)
    NOT VALID;


ALTER TABLE public.job_adverts
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (working_type_id)
    REFERENCES public.working_types (id)
    NOT VALID;


ALTER TABLE public.job_seeker_cv_educations
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (job_seeker_cv_id)
    REFERENCES public.job_seeker_cvs (id)
    NOT VALID;


ALTER TABLE public.job_seeker_cv_experiences
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (job_position_id)
    REFERENCES public.job_positions (id)
    NOT VALID;


ALTER TABLE public.job_seeker_cv_experiences
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (job_seeker_cv_id)
    REFERENCES public.job_seeker_cvs (id)
    NOT VALID;


ALTER TABLE public.job_seeker_cv_images
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (job_seeker_cv_id)
    REFERENCES public.job_seeker_cvs (id)
    NOT VALID;


ALTER TABLE public.job_seeker_cv_languages
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (job_seeker_cv_id)
    REFERENCES public.job_seeker_cvs (id)
    NOT VALID;


ALTER TABLE public.job_seeker_cv_languages
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (language_id)
    REFERENCES public.languages (id)
    NOT VALID;


ALTER TABLE public.job_seeker_cv_skills
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (job_seeker_cv_id)
    REFERENCES public.job_seeker_cvs (id)
    NOT VALID;


ALTER TABLE public.job_seeker_cv_web_sites
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (job_seeker_cv_id)
    REFERENCES public.job_seeker_cvs (id)
    NOT VALID;


ALTER TABLE public.job_seeker_cv_web_sites
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (web_site_id)
    REFERENCES public.web_sites (id)
    NOT VALID;


ALTER TABLE public.job_seeker_cvs
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (job_seeker_id)
    REFERENCES public.job_seekers (user_id)
    NOT VALID;


ALTER TABLE public.job_seekers
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (cv_id)
    REFERENCES public.job_seeker_cvs (id)
    NOT VALID;


ALTER TABLE public.job_seekers
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
    REFERENCES public.users (id)
    NOT VALID;


ALTER TABLE public.job_seekers_favorite_job_adverts
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (job_advert_id)
    REFERENCES public.job_adverts (id)
    NOT VALID;


ALTER TABLE public.job_seekers_favorite_job_adverts
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (job_seeker_id)
    REFERENCES public.job_seekers (user_id)
    NOT VALID;


ALTER TABLE public.mernis_activations
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
    REFERENCES public.users (id)
    NOT VALID;

END;
```

Comment: you have a column defined as `smallint` ?

Comment: Do not post images for textual images per [Images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).  Add table definitions for tables involved as text update to your question,

Comment: @RobertoHernandez yeah i am updated question all SQL codes showing

Comment: This: `id smallint NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY ( INCREMENT 1 START 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 2147483647 CACHE 1 )` on `working_types` is not going to work.  I would just make your `id`s `integer` and not set `MAXVALUE` as it defaults to the max for the type.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is here:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.working_types
(
    id smallint NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY ( INCREMENT 1 START 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 2147483647 CACHE 1 ),
    id smallint NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY ( INCREMENT 1 START 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 32767 CACHE 1 ),
    name character varying(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

You declare 2 smallint id columns in this table, one of which is generated by a sequence with too large a value for MAXVALUE.

Comment: Thank you very much, i am stupid) I didn't look that way because I was sure that the sql codes were correct.. I learned not to be sure). problem fixed!

Comment: FYI, since you are using the default settings for the `IDENTITY` sequence you can shorten the definition to: `id <some_int_type> NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY`. This will lessen the chances for mistakes.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver thank a lot adrian )